# How to resolve docker-compose error: `Error response from daemon: No command specified`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose to run two services: Flask and MySQL.

Here is what I got when I used `docker-compose up --build`:

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container myproj-mysql-1     Created                                                     2.4s
 ⠋ Container myproj-web-1  Creating                                                        0.0s
Error response from daemon: No command specified
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '2.5'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql:localhost
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
    restart: always
```

And here is the Dockerfile I'm trying to build for the `web` container:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY . /home

WORKDIR /home

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying `CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]` without the ENTRYPOINT line.
I typically don't see both CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a dockerfile.

Comment: It's equivalent, I suppose. Anyway, I used CMD only but I still have the same issue

Comment: I'd try building and running it without using compose (i.e. `docker build -t web . && docker run -it web`).

Comment: Yes, I did so. But I think it's hard to test this way because I have to set up the database in order to link the web server to it. I receive this error when I run the `web` image: `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Address not available)`. Is there a way to maybe link it to a MySQL docker image?

Comment: Yeah, you can create a docker network manually w/o compose but I'd just expose the MySQL to a port on localhost for testing. If your web container builds outside of compose, can compose run it using your built image?